# Registering a Firebird Blob Filter using FireDac (Delphi)

Tags: delphi, firebird, firedac

Having used Firebird SQL and Delphi for years I have always registered my own [Blob Filters](http://www.firebirdsql.org/refdocs/langrefupd25-ddl-filter.html) using FBPlus from Devrace.

As Delphi now ships with FireDac I am hoping to shift over to this technology, removing the requirement of third party data access components.

Has anyone any experience with registering Firebird SQL Blob filters in FireDac? Though I can simply access the fields as binary data and run through the routines for decompression etc, I would rather have access on a field level through the engine.

Comment: Blob filters are server side, and registering them is just executing the DDL you linked to. Could you describe what exact problem you are running into? Did FBPlus support clientside blob filters (which afaik is not part of Firebird itself)?

Comment: @MarkRotteveel Having investigated this further you are 100% correct, FIBPlus was indeed doing nothing more than intercepting the blob fields and applying the filters client side. This functionality had nothing to do with Firebird though the authors clearly borrowed the idea from Firebird itself. I have created by own intercept in FireDac to check the blob subtype and apply the corresponding filter locally. 

Please convert your comment to an answer as there is no better possible response to this question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Firebird blob filters are serverside (to convert one type of blob to another), and registering them is just executing the DDL you linked to. It sounds like FBPlus also supports blob filters clientside (as confirmed by your comment), which is - afaik - not a standard Firebird feature.

You will need to replicate this feature by calling the blob filter yourself in your code.