# How to stream an image that zipped with zlib from FireBird Database by FireDac (Delphi)

Tags: delphi, streaming, firebird, firedac

Actually, I've asked this question before but I deleted the question because probably I've asked it wrong or without correctly expressing my question or aim.

I'm connecting to our ERP Software database (FireBird v2.1) to retrieve data for exporting as XML. But at the same time I need to save all product images into separate folder (I'll sum up all data and images and upload to web server to importing for e-commerce app).

Our ERP Software Company divided the database into 2 separate parts (1 for information, 1 for files(images, files etc.) - FILES Database)
The problem is that, all assets in FILES database are zipped with zlib so I cannot stream these images via LiveBindings directly (eval error in LinkPropertyToFieldBitmap: Loading bitmap failed) I know it is normal because files are zipped and inserted as BLOB.

**I need to get these zlib compressed data as streams to use it as input for decompression procedure.**

I am planning to use below procedure for saving decompressed images as a file.

```
procedure TForm1.DecompressStream(Stream: TStream);
var
  LOutput: TFileStream;
  LUnZip: TZDecompressionStream;
begin
  Stream := TStream.Create();
  { Create the Output and Decompressed streams. }
  LOutput := TFileStream.Create('SKU OF PRODUCT.jpg', fmCreate);
  LUnZip := TZDecompressionStream.Create(Stream);

  { Decompress data. }
  LOutput.CopyFrom(LUnZip, 0);

  { Free the streams. }
  Stream.Free;
  LUnZip.Free;
  LOutput.Free;
end;
```

NOTE: Maybe the above procedure is not the right one but after be able to fetch zlib data as stream I can debug for the correcting it.
Thanks..

**UPDATE :** I am using LiveBindings for fetching data from database but using LiveBindings is not mandatory for zipped data and image processing.

Comment: 1) You should make you mind if you talk about "ZLib" or "zipped" - those are two distinct and different formats. Mistaking them might lead to decompression errors and such. 2) you may want to try adding `Calculated Field` to your Delphi datasets, that would decompress those data streams in `TDataset.OnCalcFields` event. Granted, that would make iterating through this dataset rather slow, if the image blob is not used. But with datasets made for image fetching it might be the trick, to plumber them to LiveBinding

Comment: Proper way most probably takes you to make your own descendant class from `Data.Bind.Components.TLinkPropertyToField` that would be capable of compressing/decompressing data on the fly, then registering it, then using this your new class instead of `LinkPropertyToFieldBitmap`

Comment: Would be efficient for you to uncompress all the blobs you fetch to the client?

Comment: @victoria Yes exactly that's what i want. So I can save all files to into a folder in one step.

Comment: Are you exclusively reading records by that dataset component? Or editing (inserting) as well?

Comment: @Victoria Only reading by FireDac.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You've said that you'll be using that dataset only for reading (with no writing back to the DBMS) and that your aim is actually only uncompressing BLOB streams fetched to the client. There is currently no way to intercept BLOB fetching in some comfortable way (kind of **OnBlobFetching** event).

Nearest path for intercepting BLOB stream storing would be in the **TFDDatSRow.InternalSetData** method (it's the ideal place for transforming fetched data, right before they get stored in FireDAC's internal data storage). But that would require source code modification.

Without source code modifications you can write e.g. event handler for the [**AfterGetRecord**](http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/Libraries/en/FireDAC.Comp.DataSet.TFDDataSet.AfterGetRecord) event and uncompress the stream from there. Just be very careful to not commit modified data changes into the database if you decide to overwrite fetched streams directly in fields (ideally set dataset to read-only mode).

An example:

```
procedure TForm1.FDQuery1AfterGetRecord(DataSet: TFDDataSet);
var
  BlobStream: TFDBlobStream;
  HelpStream: TMemoryStream;
begin
  { create BLOB stream for reading and writing }
  BlobStream := DataSet.CreateBlobStream(DataSet.FieldByName('Data'), bmReadWrite) as TFDBlobStream;
  try
    { create intermediate stream }
    HelpStream := TMemoryStream.Create;
    try
      { decompress BLOB stream into helper one }
      ZDecompressStream(BlobStream, HelpStream);
      { and overwrite the original BLOB stream content with uncompressed data; note, that
        TFDBlobStream must know about the modification, otherwise it won't store the data
        into the storage when this stream is released (LoadFromStream won't work here) }
      BlobStream.Clear;
      BlobStream.Write(HelpStream.Memory^, HelpStream.Size);
    finally
      HelpStream.Free;
    end;
  finally
    BlobStream.Free;
  end;
end;
```

Or similarly on lower level:

```
procedure TForm1.FDQuery1AfterGetRecord(DataSet: TFDDataSet);
var
  DataRow: TFDDatSRow;
  DataCol: TFDDatSColumn;
  InLength: LongWord;
  InBuffer: Pointer;
  OutLength: Integer;
  OutBuffer: Pointer;
begin
  { get the current row storage object }
  DataRow := DataSet.GetRow;
  { for column indexing in following calls find column by name }
  DataCol := DataSet.Table.Columns.ColumnByName('Data');
  { try to get pointer to the raw data buffer for the column with given index }
  if DataRow.GetData(DataCol.Index, rvDefault, InBuffer, 0, InLength, False) then
  begin
    { decompress the data buffer into another allocated by this procedure }
    ZDecompress(InBuffer, InLength, OutBuffer, OutLength);
    try
      { start editing this storage row }
      DataRow.BeginEdit;
      try
        { let the storage copy the decompressed data from the buffer }
        DataRow.SetData(DataCol.Index, OutBuffer, OutLength);
      finally
        { finish this storage row editing without creating new row version, so the engine
          won't take the data modification as update }
        DataRow.EndEdit(True);
      end;
    finally
      { and release the buffer allocated by ZLib library function call, input buffer used
        here belongs to FireDAC's storage }
      FreeMem(OutBuffer);
    end;
  end;
end;
```

Comment: "There is currently no way to intercept BLOB fetching in some comfortable way"... actually there is, although I'm not sure it would apply to the OP's case. You can simply inherit from TFDQuery (or other dataset) and override the CreateBlobStream virtual method. I use something like that to read and write blob fields outside of the database, while keeping them readable and writable just like standard dataset blob fields.

Comment: @Frazz and if there is no need for many forms to have it, one can even use class hi-jacking by declaring local `TFDQuery` class right abot the form declaration :-D

Comment: And one more possible avenue - though overkill in this particular situation - would be to make database-side BLOB convertor (aka those then hyped "data blades") - https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29776587

Comment: @Frazz, true, if LiveBindings reflect that intercepted class, why not go this way (if you call it comfortable is a matter of taste). You'll be just uncompressing that BLOB whenever a control requests such data through its link.

Comment: This is what I want, I just only need to save the files.. Exactly perfect. Thank you so much.

Comment: To my tastes, the SAMPLE code lacks the check if BLOB was really compressed or not. That is okay for proof-of-concept here, but the production code created around ideas of this demo, has to include that check

Comment: @Arioch'The, the OP says _"all assets in FILES database are zipped with zlib"_.

Comment: @Victoria that is a fragile assumption. Even if it is that way now, it can change any future moment. Also if he would reuse his code later, he may end up being using this handler over other tables.

Comment: @Arioch'The, so as that field name can change and you'll end up with an AV. This code is a very specific example for single dataset component for particular case described in this question. If they wanted reusable solution that would be able to detect compressed BLOB stream, it would be better to implement custom BLOB stream object.

Comment: That's why I said this code is a laconic sample, proof of concept, and that the final production code is to be based about same ideas, but made more versatile